# Worklight Studio 6 - device provisioning and app authenticity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am running Worklight Studio 6 from Worklight Enterprise Edition download with Eclipse Juno.

My application is using form security with the WASLTPA login module.  The application tests correctly.

When I add AppAuthenticity (needed for device provisioning) my client sees the following error in the console.  (None in the server log)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

drilling deeper I see:

```
/*-secure-
{"challenges":{"wl_authenticityRealm":{"WL-Challenge-Data":"o97e2ph8kguqh1vpljbio1o5k3+23.507-9.852-31.807 "}}}*/
```

I am running this on the Worklight Development Server packaged with Worklight Studio.

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned both the Enterprise Edition and Developer Edition.

Please clarify your question with the following: You have installed Worklight using the IBM Installation Manager, yes?
You have an application server (Tomcat/WebSphere/Liberty) installed and you've used the supplied Ant scripts to create the Worklight database(s), configure them, deploy the Worklight platform files to the application server, as well as deploy your project's .war file? (and of course the .wlapp /.adapter file(s)...).

If you have done the above, then you will have in your Worklight Server, now installed on the application server, the required components for App Authenticity to work.

Then there is the case of how you actually configured your project for App Authenticity.
Make sure you follow [these steps to set up App Authenticity](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html)

Comment: Note: The free Developer Edition of Worklight Studio does not contain application authenticity-related components. You must use either the Consumer Edition or the Enterprise Edition of Worklight Studio to enable application authenticity.

Comment: That's exactly so. If you use the Developer Edition and run your project on the INTERNAL Worklight Server in the Developer Edition, no actual app authenticity check will take place... For this, you have to deploy your application onto the Worklight Server that is installed on an application server using the Enterprise/Consumer Edition of Worklight, which, using the IBM Installation Manager, will also install the components required for App Authenticity.